# Spring XmlBeanFactory is deprecated

Tags: java, spring

Currently I am following site : https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-tutorial-dependency-injection-by-constructor  to learn spring.

I tried an example where we inject dependency by constructor using primitive and string based values.

The type org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.xmlbeanfactory' is deprecated.

I was unable to find suitable solution.

The code that i used was :-

```
public class Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Resource r=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
        BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  

        Employee s=(Employee)factory.getBean("e");  
        s.show();  

    }  
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow!
Most of the time the java documentation contains an explanation when something is deprecated. I recommend you to read the official java docs from spring: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanFactory.html

Comment: ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
Employee employee = ctx.getBean(Employee.class);

Comment: Same Program You can go thru this link>>> https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/core/applicationcontext-xml-config-example/

Comment: @Navin If I may give you a piece of advice, I would use up to date material when you are learning spring. It has changed a lot between now and when that tutorial was written. I recommend you to check out the official guides: https://spring.io/guides

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```
public class Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
       ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
       Employee s = context.getBean("e", Employee.class);  
       s.show();  

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Framework, `XmlBeanFactory` was the implementations of the `BeanFactory` interface for creating and managing bean based on xml configuration. However starting from spring 3.* , `XmlBeanFactory` has been marked as deprecated.

You can use `ApplicationContext` interface, or its implementations, such as `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` or `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`.

Reference:

1. [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html)
2. [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html)
3. [FileSystemXmlApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html)